# Revoking registration

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Partial Class Registration_SchoolRegistration
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CreateUserWizard1.CreatedUser

        Try
            Dim UserNameTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)
            Dim PrincipalEmail As TextBox = DirectCast(CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email"), TextBox)
            Dim DataSource As SqlDataSource = DirectCast(CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("SchoolInfo"), SqlDataSource)
            DataSource.InsertParameters.Add("TimeStamp", DateTime.Now)
            DataSource.InsertParameters.Add("PrincipalUserName", UserNameTextBox.Text.ToString)
            DataSource.InsertParameters.Add("PrincipalEmail", PrincipalEmail.Text.ToString)
            DataSource.Insert()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        Finally

        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Given Above is the code snippet i am using to store additional data to the DB.Is there any way i can revoke the registration if anything goes wrong??

I mean suppose the data entered is not in correct format or something bad happens at the server side..i do not want the user to get registered..or say i want to DE-register the user,so that he/she can register again on the site using the same credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could delete the user if something fails:

```
Dim cuw As CreateUserWizard = DirectCast(sender, CreateUserWizard)
' following is a function that inserts the user etc and returns a statuscode '
Dim insertStatus As Int32 = AddUser()
If insertStatus = 0
    Membership.DeleteUser(cuw.UserName)
End If
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1496773.aspx/1

Comment: what does insert status 0 mean ??user reg succeed or failed??